# How do I make efficient queries in Django?

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have the following models, which are relative to Django's built in models `Tag` and `Site`. Given a `Site`, what is the most efficient way to query all the related `Tag`s

```
class InlineTag(models.Model):
    tag = models.ForeignKey(Tag, null=False)
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, null=False)
    order = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=False, blank=True)

class Topic(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)
    sites = models.ManyToManyField(Site)
```

I'm doing this way currently, it seems too complex:

```
tags = []
current_site = Site.objects.get_current()
topics = Topic.objects.filter(sites=current_site)

for topic in topics:
    inline_tags = InlineTag.objects.filter(topic=topic)

    for inline_tag in inline_tags:
        tags.append(inline_tag.tag)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [reverse foreign key lookups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships) to get all the tags in one query:

```
tags = Tag.objects.filter(inlinetag__topic__sites=current_site).distinct()
```

The `distinct()` ensures that you don't get duplicate results, e.g., if a site has multiple topics that share the same tags.

As a side note, Django doesn't have a built-in `Tag` model - presumably you are using a third-party app for that.

Comment: What if I want to order the results by `InlineTag.order` ?

Comment: You can just add an `order_by()` clause after the `filter()` - e.g., `order_by('inlinetag__order')`.